# Ruby on Rails API - Export CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, csv, export-to-csv, rails-api

This may have been asked long time ago but I couldn't find a good answer anywhere.

Current situation of my application is:

- Rails API (no views)
- TypeScript JS

Now, i have been given a task to build a CSV feature...

Question is,

- how do i do it in rails api?
- how should my frontend handle this?

this is my not working endpoint:

```
   def download_csv

    headers = ['column one', 'column two', 'column three']

    csv_data = CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << headers
      csv << ["A", "B", "C"]
    end
    csv_data.strip

    send_file(
      csv_data,
      disposition: "attachment; csv-.csv",
      
    )
  end
```

Comment: You should really avoid asking multiple questions in one.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39224/297650

Comment: sorry that I am not aware of this. i thought it was a related question :pray:

Comment: posted the other question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69501769/frontend-handling-files-csv-with-rails-api

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `send_data` and not `send_file`:

```
def download_csv
  # Move the CSV generation out of the the controller 
  # for example into a service object where it can be tested in isolation
  headers = ['column one', 'column two', 'column three']
  csv_data = CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << headers
    csv << ["A", "B", "C"]
  end
  send_data(
    csv_data,
    filename: 'myfile.csv', # suggests a filename for the browser to use.
    type: :csv,  # specifies a "text/csv" HTTP content type
  )
end
```

To use `send_file` you would actually need to write the CSV to a file on the servers file system - which might make sense if the CSV generation is expensive.

Comment: okay it returns a 200, but i don't see the file being downloaded in the browser...

here's the server logs

I, [2021-10-09T03:55:15.130589 #79461]  INFO -- : method=GET path=/api/admin/users/download_csv format=html controller=Api::Admin::UsersController action=download_csv status=200 duration=11.21 view=0.08 db=6.76

Comment: Write an integration test that covers this action and then please create a second question about the frontend part of handling the upload. As mentioned above its problematic when a question is really multiple questions rolled into one as its near impossible to answer them and the scope just keeps creeping.

Comment: Understandable max. appreciate your answers...will write a new post on frontend handling