# Frontend Handling: FILES/CSV with Rails API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, csv, rails-api

I have a Rails API endpoint which sends a csv file on API request:

```
def download_csv

    headers = ['column one', 'column two', 'column three']

    csv_data = CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << headers
      csv << ["A", "B", "C"]
    end
    csv_data.strip

    send_data(
      csv_data,
      filename: 'attachment.csv',
      type: :csv,
      disposition: 'attachment; attachment.csv',
    )
  end
```

Problem:

When i hit the endpoint, it returns a 200, however my browser isn't downloading the file...

Note that i am running a Rails API server so I don't have any views only Mode controller and services.

my frontend code looks like this:

```
 <Button 
        onClick={() => {
          return API.downloadUserCsv().then(() => {
            Modal.alert({ body: 'Success' })
          })
        }}
      >
        Download CSV
      </Button>
```

```
downloadUserCsv(): Promise<AxiosResponse> {
    return this.http.get(`/admin/debug/users/download_csv`)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

```
<Button 
   onClick={() => {window.open(your backend url)})
>
```